# TAKE function in SML

Tags: sml

In the `TAKE` function which is given by

```
fun TAKE (xs,0)          = []
  | TAKE (NIL, n)        = raise Subscript
  | TAKE (CONS (x,xf),n) = x :: TAKE(xf(), n-1);
```

What are xs, x , xf?
And can you also please tell me how take function works.

Answer (score 1):

Your take function seems to operate over a data structure of some type like

```
datatype 'a stream =  NIL | CONS of 'a  *  (unit -> 'a stream)
```

Your take function iterates over the stream data structure and takes `n` elements out of it, and returns a list containing those elements.

The identifier `xs` is the function parameter that holds the stream data structure, the identifier `n` is the function parameter holding the number of elements you want to retrieve (ie take). The identifiers `x`,`xf` are patterns, they are bound to the values of the `CONS` cell, so `x` is the head (ie `'a`) and `xf` is the tail (ie `(unit -> 'a stream)`.

It is my impression (based on your question) that you need to gain a deeper understanding of SML and functional programming in general to make sense of this answer, though. Most likely you won't achieve that asking questions here. I recommend you to get a good reference book, like the ones suggested in the [information section of the SML tag](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sml/info) here in SO.

You may also want to read the section [3.5 Streams](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book-Z-H-24.html#%_sec_3.5) from the great book [Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/full-text/book/book.html). The code in the book is in Scheme. It might take a while to get it all (if you are unfamiliar with any lisp-related language), but it is worth the effort.